# Java Server and client/ RMI or Socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm developing a Desktop LAN base java server and client application

where a Client must login and also to pass some data to server.
assuming i have 10 clients that inserting record simultaneously to server.

which is the best approach in this kind of situation, should I use RMI for login and record insertion? or Sockets?

if sockets please provide a key idea for me to start with.

key points to consider
-Multithreading 
-able to send back data on client

Comment: Check my response in below question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424845/java-multithreaded-server/32093876#32093876

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect your server via internet (and/or firewalls) it is probably a hassle to do this with plain RMI. In the past I have used [Java Simon](http://dev.root1.de/projects/simon/wiki) for such tasks which is very easy to implement. However if you plan to support other clients than Java clients, then you should have a look at [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) or [Google Protocoll Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)