# Java: socket and HttpServlet

Tags: java, sockets, servlets

Multiple clients need to send XML to the server. In this case, is it better to use `Socket` or `HttpServlet?` or there is no obvious difference in developing and performance no matter using `Socket` or `HttpServlet?`

Comment: Send to what server? If you already have a servlet container, it makes sense to use a servlet. If you don't, it doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rmi vs servlets vs sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798473/rmi-vs-servlets-vs-sockets)

Comment: I think it largely depends on exactly what you need to send, who you're sending too, and how much effort you want to put into sending. See the post linked above for some basic descriptions on various kinds of connection protocols.

Comment: send XML to a weblogic server.